# SQL Query cakePHP 1.2 from 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

In cakephp 1.2, I have a table (biblio) with the list of books, and another table (tematiche) where I have the list of tags. 
 I have this code to get the list of books:

```
if (isset($autore_diviso))
        {
            $dim=count($autore_diviso);
            $i=0;
            while ($i<$dim)
            {
                $conditions[]=array ('autori LIKE ?' => array(
                    '%' . $autore_diviso[$i][0] . '%'));
                $i++;
            }
        }
        else
            $conditions[]=array('autori LIKE' => "%$a%");
        if (!$anno&&!$anno2)    // Da sistemare.
            $conditions=$conditions;
        else {
        if (!$anno)
            $conditions[] = array('anno <=' => "$anno2");          
        if (!$anno2)
            $conditions[] = array('anno >=' => "$anno");
        }
        if ($anno&&$anno2)
            $conditions[] = array('anno BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($anno,$anno2)); }
```

Now I need to get also the tag of a book, how can I add it to this query?

Comment: is both table are related ?

Comment: In the tags table there is the book id

Comment: have you defined relationship in model ?

Comment: if you define association in model its easy to to get record which you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try to bind `Tag model` in controller

**In Controller**

```
<?php

$this->Book->bindModel(array
(
    'hasMany' => array
    (
        'Tag' => array
        (
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array
            (
                'Book.id = Tag.book_id'
            )
        )
    )
));

$books = $this->Book->find('all',array
(
    'conditions' => array
    (
        'Book.id' => 'SOME_ID'
    )
));

pr($books);
exit;
```

**Result of above debugging**

```
Array
(
    [Book] => Array
    (
        [id] => SOMEID
        [name] => BOOKNAME
    )
    [Tag] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => TAGNAME
            [book_id] => SOME_ID
        )
        [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => TAGNAME
            [book_id] => SOME_ID
        )
        [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => TAGNAME
            [book_id] => SOME_ID
        )
    )
)
```